# Where can i store(keep) xml files of a java application inside the grails application

Tags: spring, grails, batch-processing

I am using spring batch processing code of a java application in my Grails application. I wanted to know where can i keep the xml files of a java application inside the grails application. How can i call that xml file from the grails application?

Comment: is config xml? or maybe some processing data, results/inputs/etc? what do you mean by "call"? please provide more details

Comment: Hi sir, I wanted to know where to keep the xml files(for eg- In the Spring Batch processing application we have a job.xml file{consists of tasklet, job etc}) in the Grails Application.

Answer (score 1):

There is a special place for such config files:

```
grails-app/conf/
```

Put it here, and file will be accessible from classpath, as a root element